# Algebraic set is irreducible iff coordinate ring is integral: Why must the field be algebraically closed?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The following is a classic result about an algebraically closed field $k$:

> An algebraic set $S$ is irreducible if and only if the coordinate ring $k[S]$ is integral, or equivalently, if and only if the ideal $\mathcal{P}(S)$ is prime.

I don't see why we need the field to be algebraically closed here. It seems to me that the result is true for any infinite field. Can anyone give me a counterexample when the field is not algebraically closed?

Comment: It will help your post if you add your definitions in an [edit]. (If you're using the definitions I think you probably are, they're not really great definitions for doing algebraic geometry over non-algebraically closed fields, so people usually don't touch that.)